# save whole of log files in a variable?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, server

I need a variable to save it content in my database - the content I want are many domains logfiles on my server -- so like `xyz.log`

So in my path `/var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/` are all the logfiles and know I need to save them all in a variable

but I don't know how.. I'm able so save the contents of the log files in variables.. but not the name of the domains itself :/

I need something that save the content in a variable AND without the .log at the end!

Does anybody can say me how?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `File` facade. Sounds like you want to get a list of all log files from your vhosts directory:

```
$files = File::files($directory);
```

Once you have all the files, you can do all operations you want (like getting the filename without the .log extension

You could take a look at the [docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html) to get a better idea.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but you say you are able to read the contents of the files through your application. So if you can read their contents, you can probably get a list of them.

Comment: yes but i read the content of the files with server commands in php - like awk, sed, cat, grep - so you can reach your server script with php commands -- like : 

date = system(" awk '{print $4,$5}' /var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/xyz.log");

Comment: Are you using Laravel at all? If yes, is your application on the same server as the logs you are trying to read? And in any case, why don't you just use `ls` and `grep` to get the list of the files?

Comment: i did it on another way.. i got the domains and got a command on it to remove the .log 

now i saved all the domains in a file - domain.list - so in domain.list are all the domains i want ! 

now i want to get the datas but with php 

so $domain = system("cat /var/www/laravel/logs/domain.list"); but this wont work.. cause domain isnt a folder - its a file.. do u know what command i can use beside that?